# Get visible TabItems in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with scrollable TabItems/Header. My TabControl ItemsSources is bound to an ObservableCollection. Is there any way to get the visible TabItems inside the TabControl.

Let's say I have 20 TabItems and only 7 are visible or 10 or more depending on the type of action performed by the user (like reducing the window). How can I programmatically retrieve the visible TabItems ?

This is the XAML code :

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  Width="440" 
                  Height="350"
                  TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                  Background="LightGray" 
                  BorderBrush="Blue">
        <TabControl.Template>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                          Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Margin="2,2,2,0"
                          IsItemsHost="true" />
              </ScrollViewer>
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                ContentSource="SelectedContent" Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </TabControl.Template>
      </TabControl>

      <Button x:Name="button" 
              Content="Add Items" 
              Margin="5" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="120" 
              Click="Button_Click" />

      <Button x:Name="button2" 
              Content="TabItems in View" 
              Margin="5" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="120" 
              Click="Button_Click2" />
```

Here's my code behind :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private static int counter = 0;
    public List<TabItem> visibleItems = new List<TabItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Data {  get;  set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = this;

      this.Data = new ObservableCollection<string>()
      {
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter,
        "item" + ++counter
      };
    }

    
    private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
      // add tab item and reduce the TabControl window:
      this.Data.Add( "newItem" + ++counter );
      
      this.tabControl.Width = 330d;
    }

    private void Button_Click2( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
      visibleItems = new List<TabItem>();
      foreach( var item in tabControl.Items )
      {
        TabItem tabItem = this.tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem( item ) as TabItem;
        if( tabItem != null && tabItem.Visibility == Visibility.Visible )
        {
          visibleItems.Add( tabItem );
        }
      }

      Debug.WriteLine( $"{visibleItems.Count}" ); // always return 20 ...
    }
  }
```

Button_Click2 event handler is where I implement the logic to retrieve the visible TabItems. But it does not work. It always return my items source total count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to iterate the item containers and accumulate the item width. Then get `ScrollViewer` of the TabPanel and collect the visible items based on the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset` (start position) and `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth` (to determine the aactual visible items).
The point is that the scroll viewer's width is measured in DIP and not items. The algorithm is more precise when you can ensure that all item containers have the same width.

You can find an iomplementation of FindVisualChild at [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#example).

```
private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var scrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(this.tabControl);
  if (scrollViewer != null)
  {
    int startIndex = GetFirstVisibleItemIndex(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset);
    double totalItemContainerWidth = 0;
    List<(object Item, TabItem ItemContainer)> visibleItems = GetVisibleItems(startIndex, scrollViewer.ViewportWidth);
  }
}

private int GetFirstVisibleItemIndex(double horizontalScrollViewerOffset)
{
  double totalItemContainerWidth = 0;
  int itemIndex = 0;
  while (totalItemContainerWidth < horizontalScrollViewerOffset)
  {
    var hiddenItemContainer = this.tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(++itemIndex) as FrameworkElement;
    totalItemContainerWidth += hiddenItemContainer.ActualWidth;
  }

  return itemIndex;
}

// Returns a collection of tuples (item and item container tuples)
private List<(object Item, TabItem ItemContainer)> GetVisibleItems(int startIndex, double viewportWidth)
{
  var visibleItems = new List<(object Item, TabItem ItemContainer)>();
  double totalItemContainerWidth = 0;
  for (int currentVisibleItemIndex = startIndex; currentVisibleItemIndex < this.tabControl.Items.Count; currentVisibleItemIndex++)
  {
    var visibleItemContainer = this.tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentVisibleItemIndex) as TabItem;
    totalItemContainerWidth += visibleItemContainer.ActualWidth;
    if (totalItemContainerWidth > viewportWidth + visibleItemContainer.ActualWidth)
    {
      break;
    }

    object visibleItem = this.tabControl.Items[currentVisibleItemIndex];
    visibleItems.Add((visibleItem, visibleItemContainer));
  }

  return visibleItems;
}
```